# MySQL Database table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I really need some help. I have this project and confused how to build its database

I have this general messaging.

students have year and section

I need to send a message in different types

1. Send to all students
2. Send to all students who wants to receive daily update
3. Send to students who are belong in specified years
4. Send to students who are belong in that year who wants to receive daily update
5. Send to students who's belong to sections
6. Send to students who's  belong to sections and who wants to receive daily update
7. Send to students who's year is and section is
8. Send to specific students

some features

```
Resend notification to new students
Time of notification to end sending
```

now here is my structure of database

```
message_queue

id
type
message
isWantToReceive
date_added
```

`type` field value is json string

i save it something like this

sample value

```
id    type                                                                                      Message        isWantToReceive   date_added
1     a:1:{s:3:"all";a:0:{}}                                                                     Hi welcome!    0                 2009-12-2
2     a:1:{s:6:"others";a:5:{s:7:"year";a:1:{i:0;s:11:"1";}s:10:"section";a:1:{i:0;s:7:"1";}}}   Hi welcome!    0                 2009-12-2
```

then i have a cron job sender that will query it and send message depending on the `type`.

My problem is when querying all the notification that been send like

get all notification that been send to `year 2` or `year 1 section 1`

since my `type` field is a json. Can you help me restructure my database design on how my features work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in addition to your `message_queue` table you should have a table as follows:
`student

id
year
section
wantsDailyUpdates`

This table will allow you to keep track of all the students and which year and section they're in. As well as whether or not they want to receive daily updates.